# How to change the email address Postfix sends out as

Tags: postfix

I currently use Postfix on an Ubuntu machine that uses Nagios for monitoring.

I'd like to change the email address that Postfix uses to send out.

Postfix just relays all its email through our Exchange Server.

Here is my current config bits

```
myhostname = mywindowsdomain.co.uk  
mydestination = $myhostname    localhost 
relayhost = IP of Exchange server 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 
inet_protocols = ipv4 
inet_interfaces = all
```

Now this works and emails out through my exchange server.

However it comes from the username of the user on the machine.

```
eg user1@mywindowsdomain.co.uk
```

I'd like it to come from the machine hostname that postfix is installed on.

How do I do this? Everything I try refuses to change the email that it's sent out as `username@mywindowsdomain.co.uk` rather than `hostname@mywindowsdomain.co.uk`

Answer (score 1):

Did you read http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic?

As alternative you might change the notification command in nagios from for example:

`command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios  *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHostname: $HOSTNAME$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $SHORTDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info: $SERVICEOUTPUT$\n$LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert - $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$`

To:

`command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios  *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHostname: $HOSTNAME$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $SHORTDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info: $SERVICEOUTPUT$\n$LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert - $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$ -- -f hostname@domainname.com`

Note the `-- -f hostname@domainname` where you instruct the mail command to pass the `-f hostname@domainname` to the MTA mail submit command (sendmail).

See `man sendmail` and search for flag `-f`

If your `mail` command actually refers to `mailx` you should use the `-r hostname@domainname.com` instead of `-- -f hostname@domainname` because mailx does not support the `-- sendmail options` feature.

Comment: Hi Thankyou for this. I did try the -f option previously and that does sort the address that it comes from out but doesnt sort the display name out. The display name still comes as Nagios with the correct email address. How would one change the display name?  It just get sconfusing becuase i have 2 seperate nagios servers in 2 seperate locations and both come from a display name called Nagios so i have no way of quickly glancing to see which it comes from. Now if i could get 1 to come from Site1 Nagios and the other from Site2 Nagios then happy days.

Comment: Look at `man sendmail` for the `-F` flag and see if that will do what you desire.