# What is the effect of $mydomain, $myorigin and $myhostname in postfix?

Tags: postfix

I tried to play with those parameters, but it seems they have no effect on sending mail from Postfix.

Basically, my problem was each mail I tried to send got rejected because the sender address didn't exist. I have a registered domain, say `example.com`. Each time I tried to send mail with postfix, issuing the command:
`mail to@otherdomain.com`, postfix tried to send it from `user@mymachinename`, where `mymachinename` was just the result of running `hostname --fqdn` in the command line, regardless what `mydomain`, `myhostname` or `myorigin` values were set to.

I faced the same problem of many others, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520399/from-address-is-hostname-domain), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151373/postfix-sending-mail-from-hostname), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202711/how-to-change-the-email-address-postfix-sends-out-as), [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/postfix-hostname-domain-name-configuration-problem-704952/), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277156/change-postfix-name-from-localhost-to-something-meaningful), and finally - [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/144986/postfix-uses-hostname-instead-of-myhostname)... (just to show you the amount of time I've putted into this...:)

I ended up setting the `/etc/hostname` file to:

```
127.0.1.1  mymachinename.example.com mymachinename
```

And add:

```
masquerade_domains = example.com
```

to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

That solved my problem, but still -  I don't believe it should be like this. What is the propose of `mydomain`,`myorigin` and `myhostname` params, if they have no effect on the sending address?

BTW - I'm on Ubuntu 17.04, using postfix  3.1.4-4

Comment: According to the [Address Rewriting](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) guide, `myhostname` and `myorigin` play a big role in computing the envelope sender.  However, (1) there are many, many other knobs for you to play with, and (2) your reading of the logs may have nothing to do with the _actual_ reason your messages got rejected.  You might want to post on the `postfix-users` list, the amount of back and forth involved in debugging this is not appropriate for [unix.se].

Comment: Postfix may also just be passing along what `mail` supplies, unless there's `generic(5)` manglements going on